# How to highlight selected item/items in a Ionic-list

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a list of items populating on a screen and just wanted to highlight the selected item/items in the list view , please help

```
 <ion-list >
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let route of Routes" (click)="selectCP(route)" >
    {{route.Name}}
  </button>  
 </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Angular conditional style function.

[class.stylename]="Some conditional statement that will return true or false"

Example:

```
<!-- This will probably go into your SCSS stylesheet -->
<style>
.highlight {
   background-color: #FFFF33 !important;
}
</style>

<!-- In your HTML code -->
 <ion-list >
  <button ion-item [class.highlight]="route == 1" *ngFor="let route of Routes" (click)="selectCP(route)" >
    {{route.Name}}
  </button>  
 </ion-list>
```

Comment: The CSS is probably override by the item-content style. Try the following.

<!-- This will probably go into your SCSS stylesheet -->
<style>
.highlight {
   background-color: #FFFF33 !important;
}
</style>

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks. <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of myAssociativeArr " [id]="item.idspecial" [class.highlight]="item.selected == 1">

Comment: For Ionic 4, I had to use --ion-background-color:#FFFF33 !important; instead of background-color: #FFFF33 !important;

Answer (score 3):

It works!

```
[class.stylename]="Some conditional statement that will return true or false"

<!-- This will probably go into your SCSS stylesheet -->
<style>
.highlight {
   background-color: #FFFF33 !important;
}
</style>

<!-- In your HTML code -->
 <ion-list >
  <button ion-item [class.highlight]="route.selected" *ngFor="let route of Routes" (click)="selectCP(route)" >
    {{route.Name}}
  </button>  
 </ion-list>

.ts

route.selected = false;
selectCP(route){
   route.selected =! route.selected;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with the built in Theme - no need for custom CSS

```
[attr.color]="item === selected ? 'primary' : ''"
```

In your code:

```
 <ion-list >
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let route of Routes" [attr.color]="route.selected ? 'primary' : ''" (click)="selectCP(route)" >
    {{route.Name}}
  </button>  
 </ion-list>
```